# Fragments inside a scrollView flickers when scrolled vertically

Tags: user-interface, android-fragments, scrollview

I have a scroll view which contains a webview, fragments and a view pager.  When I scroll   vertically the fragment part flickers.  Here is the code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapViewContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_txt_mapContainer"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: have you reached a solution for that ?